# Flutter error: list<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<dynamic, dynamic>

Tags: json, list, flutter, dictionary

**My JSON is somewhat like this:**

`{"data":{"id":1,"title":"Title 1", "images": [{"small": "link", "large": "link"}]}}`

**My model class:**

```
class Test {
final int id;
final String title;
final Images images;

Test({required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.images});

Test.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) :
    id = parsedJson["id"],
    title = parsedJson["title"],
    images = Images.fromJson(parsedJson['images']);

class Images {
  final String small;
  final String large;

Images({
   required this.small,
  required this.large
});


 factory Images.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
   return Images(
    small : json["small"] as String,
    large : json["large"] as String
  );}
}
```

Here is my api call:

```
 static Future<Test> getTest(int id) async{
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url_here"));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      dynamic body = json['data'];
      Test test = Test.fromJson(body);
      return test;
    }
    else{
      throw("message");
    }
  }
```

How do I get images.small in view class? Please let me know if I need to clear my question. I'm getting an error list is not a subtype of type Map<dynamic, dynamic> while trying to fetch images but I'm not able to covert map to list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this model. :

```
import 'dart:convert';

Test testFromJson(String str) => Test.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String testToJson(Test data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Test {
    Test({
        this.id,
        this.title,
        this.images,
    });

    int id;
    String title;
    List<Images> images;

    factory Test.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Test(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        images: List<Images>.from(json["images"].map((x) => Images.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Images {
    Images({
        this.small,
        this.large,
    });

    String small;
    String large;

    factory Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Images(
        small: json["small"],
        large: json["large"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "small": small,
        "large": large,
    };
}
```

Here List of images has been directly mapped to respective Image Class Objects which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`"images": [{"small": "link", "large": "link"}]` this is a map of list and you are casting it to map of string.
Either use `"images": {"small": "link", "large": "link"}`
or use

```dart
factory Images.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
   return Images(
    small : json[0]["small"] as String,
    large : json[0]["large"] as String
  );}
```